# Freenom Domain service not working with AWS

Tags: amazon-aws, amazon-ec2

I just got AWS working and I needed a domain for it.

I know about Freenom so I decided to get myself a domain and tried many setup methods, like the one with name servers but it didn't work even though I followed the tutorial very closely and everything seemed to be entered right.

This is my record, with the elastic IP not included:

https://gyazo.com/c8cc03efb687a62ad33fdb42d82b8783 and here is the line of code that hosts the website (using Node.JS btw)

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 443);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index2.html');
});
```

The Elastic IP is associated with my EC2 instance. Will the website work with the DNS from Amazon?

Any help?

If you are unclear about anything, ask me about it.

Comment: I don't understand anything you write of, but this. If you are asking if Elastic IP works and EC2 and Route53 work, yes, they work. I handle some.

Comment: What setup methods did you try?   Can you explain them or share links?